# Getting Started with Mobile Design Templates

Tags: visualforce, mobile

I am referring to the below post
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/08/getting-started-with-mobile-design-templates.html

The VF page is blank on the page load. I think it is going wrong with Underscore templating utility.

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0"
       showHeader="false" 
       sidebar="false"
       standardStylesheets="false"
       standardController="Contact"        
       extensions="Contacts_Ext">
```

Picture List View Template

```
<script type="text/html" id='listView'>
    alert('in the list view');
    <div class="app-wrapper">

        <nav class="main-menu">
            <a href="#">Accounts</a>
            <a href="#">Opportunities</a>
        </nav>

        <header>
            <div class="main-menu-button main-menu-button-left"><a class="menu">&nbsp;</a></div>
            <h1>Contacts</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="app-content">
            <ul id="cList" class="list-view with-swipe left-thumbs right-one-icons">
                <% for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){ %>
                    <li>
                        <div class="thumbs">
                            <% if (typeof(contacts[i].Phone) != "undefined") { %>
                                <a href="tel:<%= contacts[i].Phone %>" class="thumb thumb-1">
                                    <img class="thumb" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Mobile_Design_Templates, 'Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/images/icons/tile-phone.png')}" />
                                </a>    
                            <% } %>                

                            <% if (typeof(contacts[i].Email) != "undefined") {%>
                                <a href="mailto:<%= contacts[i].Email %>" class="thumb thumb-2">
                                    <img class="thumb" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Mobile_Design_Templates, 'Mobile-Design-Templates-master/common/images/icons/tile-email.png')}" />
                                </a>
                            <% } %>                
                            <img class="thumb thumb-3" src="<%= contacts[i].Pic %>"/>
                        </div>
                                <a href="#/contact/<%= contacts[i].Id %>" class="content">
                            <h2><%= contacts[i].Name %></h2>
                            <%= contacts[i].Title %>
                            <div class="list-view-icons">
                                <span class="icon-right-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>                
            </ul>        
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id='detailView'>
        alert('in the detail view');
        <div class="app-wrapper">

            <nav class="main-menu">
                <a href="#">Accounts</a>
                <a href="#">Opportunities</a>
            </nav>

            <header>
                    <div class="main-menu-button main-menu-button-left"><a class="left-arrow" href="#/contacts">&nbsp;</a></div>
                <h1>Contact</h1>
            </header>

            <div class="app-content">

                <div class="detail-view-header left-thumb">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img class="thumb" src="<%= contact.Pic %>"/>
                        <h1><%= contact.Name %></h1>
                        <h3><%= contact.Account.Name %></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <section class="border-bottom">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Address</h3>
                        <p>
                            <%= contact.MailingStreet %><br/>
                            <%= contact.MailingCity %>, <%= contact.MailingState %> <%= contact.MailingPostalCode %><br/>
                            <%= contact.MailingCountry %>    
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>
                            <%= contact.Title %> 
                        </p>
                    </div>    
                </section>                    
            </div>
        </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var contactRecs = new Array();
        //alert('in the contact view');
        var compiledListViewTempl = _.template($("#listView").html());
        var compiledDetailViewTempl = _.template($("#detailView").html());

        alert('in the contact view');
        $(document).ready(function() {
            getAllContacts();
        });

        function getAllContacts(){
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.Contacts_Ext.getContactRecs}',
                    function(records, e) { 
                        showContacts(records);}, 
                    {escape:false}); 
        }

        function showContacts(records) {               
            contactRecs.length = 0;                                
            for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) { 
                records[i].Pic = '{!URLFOR($Resource.BlankAvatar)}';
                if (typeof records[i].Contact_Pic__c != "undefined"){
                    records[i].Pic = $(records[i].Contact_Pic__c).attr('src');
                }
                contactRecs[records[i].Id] = records[i]; 
            }

            $('#mainContainer').empty();
            $('#mainContainer').append(compiledListViewTempl({contacts : records}));
            $(document).trigger('onTemplateReady');               
        }

        function showContactDetails(recordId) {
            var contact = contactRecs[recordId];

            $('#mainContainer').empty();
            $('#mainContainer').append(compiledDetailViewTempl({contact: contact}));
        }

        Path.map("#/contacts").to(function(){
            getAllContacts();
        });

        Path.map("#/contact/:contactId").to(function(){
            showContactDetails(this.params['contactId']);
        });

        Path.listen();    
</script>
```

```
<div id="mainContainer">
</div>
```

```
public class Contacts_Ext {
public Contacts_Ext(ApexPages.StandardController c){}

@RemoteAction
public static List<Contact> getContactRecs(){
    return [select id, name, firstName, lastName, email, title, phone, 
            MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, MailingCountry,
            Account.Name, Contact_Pic__c from Contact order by FirstName limit 20];
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks / Roshan

Answer (score 1):

It worked now. seems one of the static resources file (Mobile-Design-Templates) was not proper / corrupted.

Thanks